# spring how to send audio in reponse stream

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, audio-streaming

I have an embed tag like

```
<embed id="player" style="height:100%;width:100%"src="../PlayAudio2" controller="true" autoplay="true" autostart="True" type="audio/wav" />
```

I can able to play a file from servlet `doGet`

```
File file = new File("Z:/53611.wav");
FileInputStream fis;
byte[] buffer=null;
try {
  fis = new FileInputStream(file);
  buffer= new byte[fis.available()];
  fis.read(buffer);
  fis.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {             
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {           
  e.printStackTrace();
}     
response.setContentType("audio/vnd.wave");     
try {               
  response.getOutputStream().write(buffer);            
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

is there a way to do in spring i tried

```
  <embed id="player" style="height:100%;width:100%"src="PlayAudio.html" controller="true" autoplay="true" autostart="True" type="audio/wav" />
```

with the requesthandler code same as in servlet,but here not even the request received for `PlayAudio.html`.how can i do in Spring.

**EDIT :**
controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("main")
public class ApplicationController {

  @RequestMapping(value="Login.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showhome(){   
        return "home";
    }

  @RequestMapping(value="PlayFile.html",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void playAudio(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
            System.out.println("--playFile");
        File file = new File("Z:/53611.wav");
            FileInputStream fis;
            byte[] buffer=null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                buffer= new byte[fis.available()];
                fis.read(buffer);
                fis.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }        


           response.setContentType("audio/vnd.wave");
        try{                
            response.getOutputStream().write(buffer);              
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       

    }
}
```

i have Home.jsp in main folder under webcontent which has

```
<embed id="player" style="height:100%;width:100%" src="PlayFile.html" controller="true" autoplay="true" autostart="True" type="audio/wav" />
```

and the url mapping

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>    
  </servlet-mapping>
```

but its not working(no request is received for `PlayFile.html` handler)

Comment: How is `PlayAudio.html` generated? I don't see anything that maps to this URL in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with type="audio/wav" after removing type from embed tag i could able to play audio

```
<embed id="player" style="height:100%;width:100%" src="PlayFile.html" controller="true" autoplay="true" autostart="True" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the src needs to point to a RequestMapping URL in your Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/audio", method = RequestMethod.GET)  
public ModelAndView getAudio(HttpServletResponse) { ... response.getOutputStream().write(buffer); ... }
```

Then reference it in the src like so:

```
<embed id="player" style="height:100%;width:100%"src="<your-context-path>/audio" controller="true" autoplay="true" autostart="True" type="audio/wav" />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, it does't work.pls see the edit

Comment: assuming the Login.html mapping is working, change src="${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/main/PlayFile.html"